# How to group categorical series (like you can in Tableau

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, categorization

I don't even know how to ask this question, so forgive me if I'm not using appropriate terminology. I have a dataframe of every judicial case that is filed and disposed of. There is a series in this df called 'Court Name' which, as the name implies, lists the court where each case is filed or disposed in. Here they are:

```
df_combined['Court Name'].value_counts()
Out[27]: 
JP 6-1                            143768
JP 6-2                            111792
JP 3                               98831
JP 7                               92768
JP 4                               74083
383rd District Court               61505
JP 2                               60038
JP 5                               51013
JP 1                               35475
Jury Duty Court                    34033
388th District Court               25713
County Court at Law 7              17788
County Court at Law 1              17389
County Criminal Court 4            16877
County Court at Law 4              16823
County Court at Law 2              16812
County Criminal Court 1            16736
County Criminal Court 3            16180
County Criminal Court 2            16025
County Court at Law 5              13243
65th District Court                12635
327th District Court               11957
409th District Court               11707
County Court at Law 6              10818
120th District Court               10633
41st District Court                10308
243rd District Court                9944
Mental Health Court 1               9415
168th District Court                9252
210th District Court                9122
171st District Court                9079
384th District Court                8637
346th District Court                8470
Criminal District Court 1           8274
34th District Court                 8228
205th District Court                6141
County Court at Law 3               5283
Mental Health Court 2               4575
448th District Court                3466
Magistration                        1835
Probate Court 2                     1597
Probate Court 1                     1590
384th Competency Court               568
346th Veterans Treatment Court       153
District Clerk                        92
County Clerk                          43
County Courts at Law                  15
Family Court Services                 12
Probate Courts                         7
Domestic Relations Office              3
County Criminal Courts                 2
Deceptive Trade                        1
Name: Court Name, dtype: int64
```

I'm converting from Tableau to Python/Pandas/Numpy/Plotly/Dash, and in Tableau, you can create groups based on a series. What I need to do is to categorize all of the above outputs into

1. District Courts
2. County Courts
3. JP Courts, and
4. None of the above courts / courts I'm going to filter out.

The end desired result is a new 'Category' series, so let's say case number 1 is filed in the 388th District Court, it's category should be District, and if case 2 is filed in County Court at Law 1, it's category should be County, and so on.

I have already created lists where each of the above 'Court Name' values falls into its proper category, but I don't know what to with those lists, or even if creating these lists is appropriate. I'd like to not develop poor coding habits, so I'm relying on your collective expertise on the most efficient/elegant way to accomplish my end goal.

Thank you all so much in advance!

Jacob

Comment: If there's no guaranteed pattern and you need to manually specify all of the individual elements in a group, then you can basically create a dict of each relationship and use `map` to create the categories. Equivalently you could use `.isin` with `np.select` to define the category, but it's not all too different

Comment: But if there are some patterns that define the logic, like based on whether the string contains `'JP'` or `'County'` or `'District'`, then you would use `np.select` instead of writing out everything